# Multiple with_items in same task

Tags: ansible

Can we use multiple with_items in same task and how does the item know which one to choose?
for example:

```
command: cat /{{item}}/{{item}}
with_items:
     - etc
     - var
     - game
     - logs
```

first item is etc and var and the second item is game and logs..how can i exactly pick

#### Updates:

actually i want cat /etc/game and cat /etc/logs cat /var/game cat /var/logs

Answer (score 4):

`with_items` **iterates** over a list of items, so it's natural, that the list contains more than one item.

Your example will run the following commands:

```
cat /etc/etc
cat /var/var
cat /game/game
cat /logs/logs
```

What you seem to want is a [nested loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops):

```
- command: cat /{{item.0}}/{{item.1}}
  with_nested:
    - ['etc', 'var']
    - ['game', 'logs']
```

Comment: actually i want cat /etc/game and cat /etc/logs cat /var/game cat /var/logs